# Qt stretching the parent window from the inside?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a window with a label in it in the middle, with other widgets above and below the label. I want to stretch the label to any height and thus, resizing the window and pushing the widgets away instead of intersecting them. Is there built-in functionality for this?

EDIT: I added a layout where all the widgets are, but when I expand one of them, it pushes the others into a corner without resizing the window.

Comment: Do you mean [layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)?

Comment: I looked at this but didn't find what I needed. Which functionality am I looking for? Do I have to change something in the layout where everything is or in the layout where the label is in the middle?

Comment: You need to create a layout containing your widgets, set that layout onto the containing widget (in your case, likely a top level widget or so), and set appropriate size policies for the subwidgets so that the label expands.

Comment: what I want is for the label to expand and to push away everything, stretching the entire window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't add a layout.
Here is an example with a QVBoxLayout which will place the widgets you'll add in it above eachother.

```
#include "class.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

Class::Class(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;

    QPushButton* button1 = new QPushButton("dummy1");
    QPushButton* button2 = new QPushButton("dummy2");
    QLabel* label = new QLabel("label");

    layout->addWidget(button1);
    layout->addWidget(label);
    layout->addWidget(button2);

    setLayout(layout);
}
```

Edit: if you really want to make your label push away everything you can add `layout->addStretch();` above and under `layout->addWidget(label);` in the code

Comment: doesn't addStretch add an empty space? the documentation doesn't go in depth about this function, so I'm not quite sure what it does